# Highchart- Using PHP, MYSQL and jQuery.get to parse data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

I'm trying to display data from MYSQL.
I saw an example at http://www.blueflame-software.com/blog/using-highcharts-with-php-and-mysql/. How do I implement jQuery.get for my chart? Please I'm very new to jQuery and need lots of help thanks! Can someone get my chart to display the data?

***html for chart***

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8">

   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.8.3/scriptaculous.js"></script>
   <script src="http://www.highcharts.com/js/adapters/prototype-adapter.src.js" ></script>
   <script src="http://www.highcharts.com/js/highcharts.src.js"></script>

   <script>      
      var chart;      
      function create()
      {
         chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {renderTo: 'container', defaultSeriesType:'spline', height: 400},
                title: {text: 'SEN-2 Bulkhead Isolation'},
                xAxis: {title: {text: 'Frequency Hz'}, type: 'logarithmic'},    

                yAxis: {title: {text: 'Isolation dB'}, plotLines: [{ value: 0, width: 1, color: '#808080'}]
                },
                tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+'('+
                    this.x +' , '+ this.y +')';}
                },
                legend: {layout: 'vertical', align: 'right', verticalAlign: 'top', x: 40, y: 100, borderWidth: 0, width: 300 },
                    series: [{ 
                    name: 'SSTP Keystone STEEL', 
                    data: [[0.6,74.9 ],[0.895,81.74],[ 1.336,77.26],[ 1.993,76.81], [2.974,80.45 ],[4.438,69.41], [6.622,61.37],[9.881,79.07],[14.744,79.75],[20.000,72.33]],pointStart: 0.6
                     }, {
                    name: 'SSTP Keystone COPPER',
                    data: [[0.6,70.18 ],[0.895,85.57],[ 1.336,75.1],[ 1.993,76.09], [2.974,80.45 ],[4.438,67.32], [6.622,59.79],[9.881,72.37],[14.744,73.54],[20.000,72.8]],pointStart: 0.6
                     }, {
                    name: 'SSTP Keystone COPPER UTP antenna',
                    data: [[0.6,53.32], [0.895,56.53], [1.336,72.16], [1.993,65.82],[2.974,80.45],[4.438,63.16],[6.622,59.79],[9.881,69.63],[14.744,70.41],[20.000,73.45]],pointStart: 0.6
                    }, {
                    name: 'SSTP Keystone COPPER STP antenna',
                    data: [[0.6,62.33], [0.895,61.82], [1.336,79.92], [1.993,76.09],[2.974,76.18],[4.438,63.16],[6.622,61.37],[9.881,72.37],[14.744,74.68],[20.000,72.33]],pointStart: 0.6
                    }, {
                    name: 'absorber inside bundle shield',
                    data: []
                     }, {
                    name: 'Series6',
                    data: []
                    }, {
                    name: 'SEN-2 Baseline Isolation',
                    data: [[0.6,76.07], [0.895,90.28], [1.336,77.26], [1.993,82.58],[2.974,83.53],[4.438,74.63],[6.622,63.45],[9.881,76.86],[14.744,76.98],[20.000,72.33]],pointStart: 0.6
                     }],    
                    });
      }

      function destroy()
      {
         if( chart ) {
            chart.destroy();
            delete chart;
            chart = null;
         }   
      }

      document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
         $('destroy').observe("click", function(){destroy();})
         $('create').observe("click", function(){create();})
         create();
      });

   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <a id="destroy" href="#">destroy</a> | <a id="create" href="#">create</a>
   <div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 900px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to tab those code snippets back a bit in your code editor before pasting them back in to make them a little easier to read.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock the codes are setup in my editor as they should be. I had to tab it in here so that it will show up on the site.

Comment: I edited the question to fix indentation.

Comment: Cool yes that looks a lot neater. Thanks Mark!

Comment: Looks like in your output you are using a tab to separate the first two fields and then a comma to separate the last one. Then in your JS you are removing this comma altogether, so the x and y values are concatenated. This can't be right...

Comment: Mark I got that sample output from http://www.blueflame-software.com/blog/using-highcharts-with-php-and-mysql/...but yes I added a comma when I was testing the output in a table and forgot to remove it.

Comment: Please explain your data a little more, and what kind of graph you are trying to generate. The example from blueflame software is a line chart, with time on the X axis and visits on the Y axis. Your TSV output has a name, plus X and Y. So are you trying to make a scatter plot? If you built this same chart in Excel, what would it look like?

Comment: I'm using a basic line (spline) chart like the example here http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic. My data is simple xy coordinates. I posted the MYSQL create script showing only one xy coordinate set here is an example of the data with more xy coordinates....   series: [{name: 'SSTP Keystone STEEL', data: [[0.6,74.9 ],[0.895,81.74],[ 1.336,77.26],[ 1.993,76.81], [2.974,80.45 ],[4.438,69.41], [6.622,61.37],[9.881,79.07],[14.744,79.75],[20.000,72.33]],pointStart: 0.6

Comment: // Load data asynchronously using jQuery. On success, add the data
// to the options and initiate the chart.
// This data is obtained by exporting a GA custom report to TSV.
// http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
jQuery.get('data2.php', null, function(tsv) {                                                                     I got this part of the script from         
blueflame-software.com/blog/using-highcharts-with-php-and-mysql/                                                           I don't know how it works so I was hoping that someone could help me figure it out.

Comment: The data for http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic contains only a series of Y values; it does not contain x/y pairs....

Comment: I think I can best help you if you add sample TSV output in your post. That way I don't have to create the MySQL table, etc.

Comment: I modified my chart to accommodate for two pairs. Maybe I should resubmit this question with my working static chart.

Comment: The real problem is that I haven't yet taken time to fully examine your code. Doing that now. Sample TSV data, including multiple rows from one series, would still be super helpful.

Comment: I updated my post with the static chart.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's a complete solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
</head><body>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 900px"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.highcharts.com/js/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    var options = {
        chart: {renderTo: 'container', defaultSeriesType:'spline', height: 400},
        title: {text: 'SEN-2 Bulkhead Isolation'},
        xAxis: {title: {text: 'Frequency Hz'}, type: 'logarithmic'},
        yAxis: {title: {text: 'Isolation dB'}, plotLines: [{ value: 0, width: 1, color: '#808080'}]},
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+'('+this.x +' : '+ this.y +')';
            }
        },
        legend: {layout: 'vertical', align: 'right', verticalAlign: 'top', x: 40, y: 100, borderWidth: 0, width: 300 },
        series: []
    };

    jQuery.get('data2.php', null, function(tsv) {
        var data = {};
        tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g); // split into rows
        for (var row=0, rows=tsv.length; row<rows; row++) {
            var line = tsv[row].split(/\t/g), // split into columns
                series_name = line[0],
                x = Number(line[1]),
                y = Number(line[2]);
            if (!data[series_name]) data[series_name] = [];
            data[series_name].push([x,y]);
        }
        for (var series_name in data) {
            options.series.push({
                name: series_name,
                data: data[series_name]
            });
        }
        new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

});
</script>
</body></html>
```

I tested it with this TSV data:

```
SSTP Keystone STEEL 0.6 74.9 
SSTP Keystone STEEL 0.895   81.74
SSTP Keystone STEEL 1.336   77.26
SSTP Keystone STEEL 1.993   76.81
SSTP Keystone STEEL 2.974   80.45 
SSTP Keystone STEEL 4.438   69.41
SSTP Keystone STEEL 6.622   61.37
SSTP Keystone STEEL 9.881   79.07
SSTP Keystone STEEL 14.744  79.75
SSTP Keystone STEEL 20.000  72.33
```

What I'm doing is looping thru the TSV and building the `data` variable like an associative array keyed on the series name, like this:

```
{
    'SSTP Keystone STEEL': [[0.6,74.9],[0.895,81.74],...],
    ...
}
```

Then I am looping through the `data` variable and constructing `options.series` in the format that HighCharts expects - an array of objects with a `name` property and a `data` property.

Comment: Did you rewrite data2.php script? Maybe I did something with my script? The chart is not populating. Did you write a MYSQL table with data?